Is there a name for, or a study of, surjections whose level sets are open and converge to constancy at their boundary?
Question
Is there a name for surjective functions whose level sets are open and have arbitrarily small derivative near their boundary?
More details & example
Consider the products of all the dyadic and ternary rationals which I shall denote $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$
Now let $p^{\nu_p(x)}$ denote the highest power of $p$ that divides $x$.  So for example $2^{\nu_2(24)}=8$.
Now consider the function $f(x)=x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$.
In the Real topology function $f$ has the property of a "constant boundary" which is the subject of this question.  This is what I mean by it: Take any $y\in\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ and its level set (i.e. the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=y$),  will comprise an open set which converges to $y$.
For example the set of all $x$ such that $f(x)=\frac{16}3$ is:
$\left\{4+\frac{2^{2-6n}}3, 5+\frac{2^{-6n}}3:n\in\Bbb Z\right\}$ and that is an open set having boundary $\frac{16}3$
Therefore we might say that the function's level sets converge to constancy at their boundary.
Motivation & Related
My motivation is to study the orbits of the given function $f$, with the aid of this property. I wouldn't be surprised if there is no name for this property, but maybe there is some obvious (to you) observation.  I also can't get away from the idea that the function $f$ somehow induces a new topology on the set.
